# Django: How to create a model from a definition in another module

Tags: django, django-south, django-orm, django-syncdb

Lets say I have this Django setup:

```
appA - models.py
     - views.py
     - etc...

global - models.py
```

What I want is import the models from `global.models` in `appA.models` so that they are treated as a normal `appA` models by syncdb and south.

global.models:

```
from django.db import models
class Foo(models.Model):
    #django model stuff
```

appA.models:
try 1:

```
from global.models import *

>>manage.py schemamigration appA --auto
>>does not see Foo
```

try 2:

```
from global.models import Foo

class Foo(Foo):
    pass

>>manage.py schemamigration appA --auto
>>Error: One or more models did not validate:
>>appA.Foo: 'foo_ptr' has a relation with model <class 'global.models.Foo'>, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from .models import Foo

class Foo(models.Model):
    #stuff

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: >>manage.py schemamigration appA --auto- 
>>Deleted model appA.Foo
>>Created 0005_auto__del_foo.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate runengine

Comment: why not make your Foo as an abstract?

Answer (score 0):

*global* is a python statement, you should not use it to name one of your package. Try using a different name, and don't forget to put a `__init__.py` file in the directory to turn it into a python package.